# In Smallworld, do Fortresses pay the +1 VC only on the turn they are placed, or do they each pay for every turn that the race is active?

Tags: small-world

The question is regarding the fortresses. If they each pay +1 VC for each turn that they are on the map and your race is active, then they become quite powerful because the VC will be building exponentially. Is this the case, or do they only each pay one VC on the turn that they are placed and then are only good as a defensive bonus for there on out?

Comment: They're increasing linearly, not exponentially.  And that's only if people don't attack them.

Comment: Or, arguably, quadratically, if you count the total effect while having been in play.

Answer (score 6):

They work at the end of each your turn (not only when they are placed).

Even if it might by ambiguous in the [Smallworld rules](http://static.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/img/sw_rules_en.pdf),

> **Fortified**
>
> Once per turn, as long as your Fortified Race
> is active, you may place 1 Fortress in a
> Region you occupy. The Fortress is worth 1
> bonus Victory coin at turn's end, unless you
> are In Decline. The Fortress also augments your Region's
> defense by 1 (just as if you had an additional Race token
> stationed there), even if you are In Decline.
> Remove the Fortress if you abandon the Region
> or when an enemy conquers it. There can only
> ever be a maximum of 1 Fortress per Region,
> and a maximum of 6 Fortresses on the map.

1. Everywhere else, symbol +1 VC on a land or token (such as Fortress) says that it works each turn.
2. If it were only about the end of the current turn, then the sentence *at turn's end, unless you are In Decline* wouldn't make sense (as you cannot place anything when you are in decline, unless you are Stout, but you cannot be Stout and Fortified at the same time).

Comment: Oh but there are ways you can be Stout and Fortified at the same time if you are playing with more than just the base set. I believe the Tales & Legends and Realms expansions have options for multiple powers. Still, your explanation of the rules would stand. You are either in decline or you are not, regardless of what you can do while in decline. Fortresses give points every turn you are active (not in decline).

Answer (score 2):

At the end of each turn where your active race occupies a Fortress (including the turn in which it was placed), you get 1 point for each occupied Fortress.

This is not an exponential point growth. For example, on the third turn you held a Fortress, you do not get 3 points, you just get the standard 1 point each turn.

Comment: Yes, you are correct... I was saying exponentially because at the end of turn 1 you receive 1 coin, turn two... 2 coin for a total of three for both turns, turn three... 3 coin for a total of six for all three turns, turn four... 4 coin for a total of ten received etc... With a race like the Skeletons or the Amazons, this power becomes quite overwhelmingly powerful, especially in a two player game. (this is of course if your opponent is not able to attack any of the fortresses to elliminate them.)

Comment: I'm not clear how this answers the question..?